# How to loop two values from checkbox with two insert query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

i have checkbox with two values like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="analysis[]" value="'.$rows['name'].'_'.$rows['cost'].'">
```

i want loop first value (name) with insert query and get sum second value (cost) in one var to insert it in another insert query .

i can explode it

```
$analysis = explode("_", $_REQUEST['analysis']);
$name = $analysis[0];
$cost = $analysis[1];
```

but It's complicated for me with loop first value and sum second value

my Full php code to understand what i want

```
$allAnalysis = $_REQUEST['analysis_type'];
$totalCost = 0;
foreach($allAnalysis as $k=>$analysis)
{
$analysis = explode("_", $analysis);
//$name = $analysis[0];
$cost = $analysis[1];
$totalCost += $cost;
}

$payment_option =  $_REQUEST['payment_option'];

$amount_paid =  $_REQUEST['amount_paid'];
if (!$amount_paid){$amount_paid =  '0.00';}

$amount_remaining =  $analysis_cost - $amount_paid ;
if ($amount_remaining == '0'){$amount_remaining =  '0.00';}

$analysis_due = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_REQUEST['analysis_due']));

// analysis invoice number
$invoice_num = mysql_query(" SELECT max(invoice_id) FROM invoice ");
$invoice_num = mysql_fetch_array($invoice_num) + '1';
$invoice_num = 'H'.date('Y').date('m').str_pad($invoice_num,3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

$invoice_insert = "INSERT INTO invoice (
                        invoice_id ,
                        analysis_cost ,
                        payment_option ,
                        amount_paid ,
                        amount_remaining ,
                        analysis_date ,
                        analysis_due ,
                        invoice_num ,
                        userid
                    ) VALUES ( 
                        NULL ,
                        '".$totalCost."' ,
                        '".$payment_option."' ,
                        '".$amount_paid."' ,
                        '".$amount_remaining."' ,
                        NOW() ,
                        '".$analysis_due."' ,
                        '".$invoice_num."' ,
                        '".$_SESSION['userid']."'
                    )";

if (mysql_query($invoice_insert) === TRUE) 
{
$invoice_id = " SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() " ; 
foreach($allAnalysis as $k=>$analysis)
{
$analysis = explode("_", $analysis);
$analysis_type = $analysis[0];
$analysis_inser = "INSERT INTO analysis (
                        analysis_id ,
                        horse_id ,
                        analysis_type ,
                        invoice_id
                    ) VALUES ( 
                        NULL ,
                        '".$_GET['horse']."' ,
                        '".$analysis_type."' ,
                        '".$invoice_id."'
                    )";
}                       
}
```

Comment: You could use explode function.http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Are you getting value of `name` and `cost` in `value` ? I guess not !!!

Comment: @C2486 i get already them sir , see the edit

Comment: @D.Dimitrov see edit

Comment: What's complicated, you already get the values you need, please be more specific.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov i want use (name) in insert query looping and sum(cost) with one var to insert it in another query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using array `analysis[]` use any loop like `foreach`

```
$allAnalysis = $_REQUEST['analysis'] ?? [];
$totalCost = 0;
foreach($allAnalysis as $k=>$analysis){
  $analysis = explode("_", $analysis);
  $name = $analysis[0];
  $cost = $analysis[1];
  $totalCost += $cost;
  //Your DB stuff
}
// Use $totalCost for another purpose
```

Another trick to just get total `cost` from your checkbox value

```
$arr = ["abc_111","abc_222","abc_333"];
$arrStr = explode(",",strrev(join(",",$arr)));
print_r(array_sum($arrStr));
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1056879)

Comment: thanks sir , so i can use '$name' with insert query in this loop but how sum '$cost' in one var to add it in another query not in same looping

Comment: You must use another variable like `totalCost` to get sum of all cost

Comment: i will try it now and i will tell you what i do

Comment: i try it but not working good , it is insert only one record not all selected

Comment: i share it now , I expect a lot of mistakes

Comment: i found sloution , thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323467/how-to-loop-only-first-value-from-checkbox-with-insert-query