# How to loop only first value from checkbox with insert query

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, explode

i have checkbox with two values like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="analysis[]" value="'.$rows['name'].'_'.$rows['cost'].'">
```

i want loop only the first value (name) with insert query

that is my code , working but it only insert one record every time . loop not working

```
$allAnalysis = $_REQUEST['analysis'];
foreach($allAnalysis as $analysis)
{
    $analysis = explode("_", $analysis);
    $analysis_name = $analysis[0];
    $analysis_insert = "INSERT INTO analysis (
                            analysis_id ,
                            analysis_name 
                        ) VALUES ( 
                            NULL ,
                            '".$analysis_name."'
                        )";         
}
```

Comment: You do realise that only the CHECKED checkboxes will get sent to the PHP Script from the HTML form dont you?

Comment: So what's the issue you face? Also do this come as part of the php echo '<input type="checkbox" name="analysis[]" value="'.$rows['name'].'_'.$rows['cost'].'">'; ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i cannot understand what you mean

Comment: @Rinsad Ahmed the code working good but only insert one record , i want insert all the record is CHECKED

Comment: Could you share the code where you populate the checkbox array? Maybe you are really not having multiple values on the screen. Share the generated HTML from the browser either. It will help to guide you easily

Comment: Where is your SQL insert code in query ?  İ think, it just insert the last one. Am i right ?

Comment: @Fatihd yes you are right . only last one

Comment: @RinsadAhmed i get date from database and iam sure it is right like that *$all_names .= ' <input type="checkbox" name="analysis[]" value="'.$rows['name'].'_'.$rows['cost'].'">'.$rows['name'];*

Comment: curious as to the api used to connect/query with, it's unknown and I don't see where you're executing it, or others for that matter. I hope you're not using that old / deprecated version of `mysql_*` are you? If so, you'd better hop onto mysqli_* or pdo so you don't have to rewrite a bunch of code.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner my problem is so simple i forget put SQL query inside foreach , now the code is working good . thanks

Comment: I know that and I'm glad you got your solution but what you replied to me with didn't answer my question to you.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I did not think that was a question .. I thought it was advice, was not it ? i use *MySQL Database Version 5.7.17*

Comment: by api meaning, mysql_ to connect? mysqli_? PDO? other?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner   i do not use API , DO YOU MEAN MY CONFIG.PHP ? sorry if i cannot understand you but i try

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Can you explain so I understand please , thanks

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  Sure I do not want to rewrite the code once again when I upload the program to an online site. I am currently working on a app server

Comment: If you have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php it shows 3 different types of connecting with a mysql database. Surely you executed that query of yours with one of those. How "are" you executing it? with mysql_? with mysqli_? with PDO?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner NOW i understand you . sorry - i use *mysql* in my config.php i used *mysql_connect* and *mysql_select_db* to connect my database

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner AND in all my files i used MYSQL Functions like *mysql_query*,*mysql_fetch_array*

Comment: ok, so it's the mysql api you're using. Are you planning on using this for long? If so, I'd look into switching over to either the mysqli_ API or PDO as soon as you can. What you're using is rather old and no longer supported in newer / recent PHP versions. Don't wait till it's too late or you're going to be scrambling to convert all of it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner okay sir Your advice is very important
.. Can you put to me a topic for how to convert from MSQL to MSQLI (I think it 's easier for me than PDO )

Comment: You will have to Google that. Use "mysqli php" and "pdo php" and you'll most likely see php.net and is the one to visit.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner okay i will use search , Thank you .. I am happy talking to you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please add SQL query inside foreach.

```
foreach (...){
....
 $analysis_insert = "INSERT INTO analysis (
                            analysis_id ,
                            analysis_name 
                        ) VALUES ( 
                            NULL ,
                            '".$analysis_name."'
                        )";         

/// add here your query
mysql_query( $analysis_insert);

}
```

Comment: thanks so much sir it is insert now all record , you are right .. thanks :)